# Preg_match ,check for spaces at the beginning and at the end of the string

Tags: regex

I need to make expression or if instruction to check if the string have a space at the beginning or at the end of the string ,BUT not in the string.
for example.
" asd" - false
"asd " - false
" sdf " -false
"asd asd" - true

Comment: i don't understand how to make it i know than i should use /^.../ and /...$/

Comment: @VladimirShabuniayeu What about multiple spaces? `\s+` matches 1 or more times, where `\s` matches a single space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
preg_match('/^\s|\s$/', $str);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$string = " test";
if(trim($string) != $string)
{
    echo "string has a space at the end or beginning";
}
```

Or one line code:

```
echo trim(" asd") != " asd" ? "false" : "true";
```

However it's better to not use regular expressions here as it's not emergency, but here is what you want:

```
preg_match("/^( .+|.+ )$/", $string); // if matched it has spaces at the end or beginning
```